# Doesn't constant icons in dock or top-bar cause to screen burn-in?

Tags: display, icons, screen, dock, top-bar

maybe it is a silly question or maybe i am too sensitive but i always think with myself does showing just a constant static icon in Ubuntu's dock or its top-bar cause to screen burn-in problem?

i use my laptop for around 6 continuous hours with display on every day. so this is my concern. during these 6 hours or so the dock and the top-bar are constant without any animation or change in color or etc.

so, isn't any risk for burned or hot pixels in these two areas especially with white constant icons in top-bar?

[image]

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://www.cnet.com/tech/home-entertainment/oled-screen-burn-in-how-to-prevent-it-and-why-you-shouldnt-be-worried/

Answer (score 1):

It obviously depends on the model of the screen, but I've never seen a screen burn-in problem occur on static areas of the screen of any monitor or screen that I've ever used with Ubuntu. I normally lock the screen and turn off the monitor when I'm away from the screen for more than a minute or two in order to save power and prevent screen burn-in. It should also be noted that energy efficient screens have a longer lifespan than a non-energy efficient screens as well as using less energy when drawing power from a battery.